# How to audit login in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, blazor-webassembly

hello community I am implementing a system to audit the modifications that are made in my application carry out the process that is described in this article:

https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/audit-trail-implementation-in-aspnet-core/?unapproved=50671&moderation-hash=71700d12d4ebaf51ad9d90c4a9834324#comment-50671

but I don't know how to get the login of my application, to login I use web token and authentication provider.

any suggestion how to do it? I don't know if it can be done with serilog or something similar

this is my code:

```
public class Audit
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string TableName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public string OldValues { get; set; }
    public string NewValues { get; set; }
    public string AffectedColumns { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryKey { get; set; }
}

public enum AuditType
{
    None = 0,
    Create = 1,
    Update = 2,
    Delete = 3
}

public class AuditEntry
{
    public AuditEntry(EntityEntry entry)
    {
        Entry = entry;
    }
    public EntityEntry Entry { get; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string TableName { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, object> KeyValues { get; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    public Dictionary<string, object> OldValues { get; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    public Dictionary<string, object> NewValues { get; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    public AuditType AuditType { get; set; }
    public List<string> ChangedColumns { get; } = new List<string>();
    public Audit ToAudit()
    {
        var audit = new Audit();
        audit.UserId = UserId;
        audit.Type = AuditType.ToString();
        audit.TableName = TableName;
        audit.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
        audit.PrimaryKey = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(KeyValues);
        audit.OldValues = OldValues.Count == 0 ? null : JsonConvert.SerializeObject(OldValues);
        audit.NewValues = NewValues.Count == 0 ? null : JsonConvert.SerializeObject(NewValues);
        audit.AffectedColumns = ChangedColumns.Count == 0 ? null : JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ChangedColumns);
        return audit;
    }
}

public abstract class AuditableIdentityContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public AuditableIdentityContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Audit> AuditLogs { get; set; }
    public virtual async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(string userId = null)
    {
        OnBeforeSaveChanges(userId);
        var result = await base.SaveChangesAsync();
        return result;
    }
    private void OnBeforeSaveChanges(string userId)
    {
        ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
        var auditEntries = new List<AuditEntry>();
        foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
        {
            if (entry.Entity is Audit || entry.State == EntityState.Detached || entry.State == EntityState.Unchanged)
                continue;
            var auditEntry = new AuditEntry(entry);
            auditEntry.TableName = entry.Entity.GetType().Name;
            auditEntry.UserId = userId;
            auditEntries.Add(auditEntry);
            foreach (var property in entry.Properties)
            {
                string propertyName = property.Metadata.Name;
                if (property.Metadata.IsPrimaryKey())
                {
                    auditEntry.KeyValues[propertyName] = property.CurrentValue;
                    continue;
                }
                switch (entry.State)
                {
                    case EntityState.Added:
                        auditEntry.AuditType = Enums.AuditType.Create;
                        auditEntry.NewValues[propertyName] = property.CurrentValue;
                        break;
                    case EntityState.Deleted:
                        auditEntry.AuditType = Enums.AuditType.Delete;
                        auditEntry.OldValues[propertyName] = property.OriginalValue;
                        break;
                    case EntityState.Modified:
                        if (property.IsModified)
                        {
                            auditEntry.ChangedColumns.Add(propertyName);
                            auditEntry.AuditType = Enums.AuditType.Update;
                            auditEntry.OldValues[propertyName] = property.OriginalValue;
                            auditEntry.NewValues[propertyName] = property.CurrentValue;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        foreach (var auditEntry in auditEntries)
        {
            AuditLogs.Add(auditEntry.ToAudit());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a `custom Controller` that inherits from the `built-in Controller`, and added a `CurrentUserName` property. The problem is that `Controller.User` is not yet initialized in the `Controller` constructor. I override `Controller.OnActionExecuting()`, where the User exists, and use that to set my custom property.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var authenticatedUser = User;
    if (authenticatedUser != null)
    {
        string userId = authenticatedUser.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        if (userId != null)
        {
            _currentUserId = int.Parse(userId, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            string userName = authenticatedUser.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name);
            _context.CurrentUserName = userName;
            _userIsAdmin = authenticatedUser.IsInRole(ConferenceRoleTypes.WebAdmin);
        }
    }

    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, but I really don't understand where in my code to add the method you provided me and how it captures a record of who is logged in